# Weka : Install in RedHat for users to view reports in web browser and model to be created by admin user only

Tags: java, open-source, weka, data-mining

I have a requirement to deploy / install Weka on my Linux box via a ssh session :

```
uname -a
Linux xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxxxx 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The installation should be such that around 100 users of my org would be able to view reports created by some admin users on the web - something like a local intranet service.

I downloaded weka from [Weka for Linux](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html) and issued the following command:

```
java -Xmx1000M -jar weka.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
        at weka.gui.LogWindow.<init>(LogWindow.java:252)
        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.<clinit>(GUIChooser.java:215)
```

I am using ssh secure client tool to connect from windows to my linux box. How can I solve this issue?

The xserver does not seems to run in the box:

```
 ps -ef | grep x | grep ser
```

Also how I can setup weka as a web app for users to view reports. I should be able to restrict specific users with specific views and only a couple of admin users should be able to create / modify a model.

Comment: A) use the command line of Weka, instead of the GUI, or B) install a GUI server that you can *remotely* access. This will be more pain. But also consider whether Weka is the proper tool for your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run any GUI application, you need to install either X or a virtual framebuffer (e.g. Xvfb) into your box.

Comment: I can ask my IT people to install X server in the box - but how can I make  weka tool be available as setup requested in my org question. This installation seems to be a standalone setup

Comment: Weka is a stand-alone application, and cannot be deployed as a web app. You can, though, use its API for integrating it with your own application, provided that you have one.

Comment: oh .. but then which open source data mining software has such a functionality .. ok even if we deploy weka on each client box - then is there a way to restrict users to not modify / change any views, The admin can only create nodes / views / model and users can only see the details or report of same.